# Vim Solarized colorscheme not working properly with html

Tags: html, vim, color-scheme, iterm2

I installed the solarized colorcheme for Vim using Pathogen. My .vimrc contains only the following:

```
execute pathogen#infect()

syntax enable
set background=dark
colorscheme solarized
```

However, the tags for an html file are displaying as grey when they should be blue, judging by the screenshots provided at http://ethanschoonover.com/solarized. I am using iTerm2, TERM=xterm-256color, and I am using the Solarized colorscheme for iTerm2.

[image: Incorrect html color scheme]

Comment: Could it be that the file type is not being recognised? What happens if you execute this command? `: set ft=html`

Comment: Nothing new happens if I execute that command. I'm confident that Vim is recognizing the file as HTML.

Comment: Did you ever manage to resolve this issue @xvtk? I am having the same issue in Vim 8 within `urxvt` terminal. The tags are highlighted as intended in GVim, but I don't want to use GVim.

Comment: Unfortunately, I never managed to get it resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switching to solarized8 for vim seems to have done the trick: https://github.com/lifepillar/vim-solarized8